# HTMLInputElement's .value can't be watched with Mutation Observers

Tags: javascript, html, html-input, mutation-observers

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/geoyws/pen/VmgWXK?editors=1011).

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="HRM"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
let input = document.querySelector('input')

let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      //let value = mutation.target.value
      console.log(mutation)
      console.log(mutation.attributeName)
    }
  })
}).observe(input, {
  attributes: true
})

input.placeholder = 'asdfsd'
input.value = "Y U NO FIRE"
```

When the `placeholder` attribute is changed, the Mutation Observer fires.
But when the `value` attribute is changed, the Mutation Observer does not fire. Does anyone have solid understanding of why? (Hopefully backed with a link to the ECMAScript/HTML5 standards.)

Does anyone know how we can watch for when JavaScript makes changes to `HTMLInputElement`'s `value` via `input.value`?

Comment: because value at this time is a property not an attribute ?

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido ... that's what I need clarified... got any links to a reputable source?

Comment: on mobile rn, but will try to find this out yep. But basically, placeholder just like style when modified also change the attribute, while it's not the case for value.

Comment: it's here : https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#concept-input-checked-dirty-flag well the paragraph before for value but it's the same for checked.

Answer (score 1):

The Mutation Observer will observe changes in the DOM but when you type text inside an input, if you inspect the DOM element, there is not change. So we need to trigger that change.

You can do that by setting the input attribute to the inserted value. See the code bellow.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('inp');
let result = document.getElementById("result");

let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      result.innerHTML = mutation.target[mutation.attributeName];
    }
  })
}).observe(input, {
  attributes: true
});

input.oninput = () => {
  input.setAttribute("value", input.value);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="HRM" value="" id="inp" />

<p>Mutation observer result:<br />
  <div id="result"></div>
</p>
```